# Interface Versioning

Tags: delphi, dll, interface, com, version

Where I work we've just finished releasing a feature that uses a dll that heavily relies on interfaces. The dll and all client applications are written in Delphi. There is no registration needed. This dll is not a proper com server. The only constraint is that the unit containing the interface is accessible to both the dll and the client applications. This allowed us to pass complex data to and from the applications that use this dll without needing to resort to record pointers, arrays or extremely fat function signatures and without the baggage that a bpl or a fully compliant COM server would introduce.

It looked like it solved a major problem we'd had with no down sides. Unfortunately there is a downside. Any change to an interface after it's been released requires a subsequent recompile of any consumers of that interface. This is fine for projects that are all part of the same release cycle but some of our projects have different release schedules.

I've researched this a bit and it looks like it's a common practice to introduce a new interface that inherits from the previously released interface rather than modify the original interface.

```
type
  IOriginalInterface = interface
  ['{8B598EC1-AD92-4144-A1BE-9062C5EA0748}']
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  INewInterface = interface(IOriginalInterface)
  ['{DD9D9DE0-0F87-4BC5-803C-74C8AB0F3E39}']
    procedure DoSomethingElse;
  end;
```

This ensures older executables compiled against the original interface continue to work.

I've noticed with the RAD Studio open tools api the interfaces are renamed whenever a new one is introduced. So rather than giving the newest interface a new name the newest interface gets the original interface's name and the original interface is renamed.

```
type
  IOldInterface = interface
  ['{8B598EC1-AD92-4144-A1BE-9062C5EA0748}']
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  IOriginalInterface = interface(IOldInterface)
  ['{DD9D9DE0-0F87-4BC5-803C-74C8AB0F3E39}']
    procedure DoSomethingElse;
  end;
```

This has obviously worked well for the RAD Studio team as well as third party extension vendors. This ensures that any clients that get recompiled will be using the latest interface without needing any code changes. I assume this works because the name is irrelevant and after the code is compiled all that remains is the interface definition, which is resolved using the GUID.

Having said all that, is this a good solution to the interface versioning problem we are now facing? Are there any other issues I need to be aware of?

Comment: I'm not a Delphi specialist, but in terms of pure COM. renaming the interface is kinda weird (creating a derived new interface w/o changing the original one is 100% standard and very common, like IHTMLDocumentX). Ok, yes, only the GUIDs are important when deployed, but source code written by humans still uses *names* not GUIDs.

Comment: I do wonder if you are over thinking this. Do you really need your DLL to support multiple different versions of these interfaces? If you do then you are entering into the realm of DLL hell and you do indeed need to worry about versioning. If you can mandate that each consumer of the DLL uses a specific version of the DLL, then you need not worry about this at all. You can modify the interfaces without creating new ones. You just need to build both DLL and consumer off the same source.

Comment: One other point to make is that the ToolsAPI operates in a very different scenario from the one you describe. The ToolsAPI is updated and modified for each new version of Delphi, and all packages that link to it must be re-compiled. What's more, the ToolsAPI supports a plugin architecture whereas for your scenario you control all of the code, as I understand it. So, if you do need to enter DLL hell, you should not regard the ToolsAPI approach as a model for dealing with DLL hell.

Comment: As I said, we have several integrated products with independent release cycles. Additionally, many of our clients have policies delaying software updates for months after they are released. It is almost guaranteed we will have a mix of old and new software running on the same system.

Comment: I understand that. But you don't need all the different executables to run the exact same version of the DLL. Or do you? I hope you are not planning to put the DLL into the system32 directory!

Comment: There is only one version of the dll on a system at a time and it is in a subfolder beneath where the application is installed. Maintaining side-by-side versions of the same dll would be another form of dll hell I'd rather avoid.

Comment: No, DLL hell is when one DLL has to support multiple different versions of the same interface/functionality. It is a testing nightmare. What you are proposing couples the behaviour of all your programs together. They will all be interdependent. A change in the DLL to fix a problem for one program could as a consequence break all your other programs. You will now need to test all possible permutation of app and DLL. So, if you have 10 apps, and after a period of time 10 possible different versions of the DLL, then you need to test 100 different permutations. This is DLL hell.

Comment: By way of contrast, making each new version of an app be tied to a specific version of the DLL means that you isolate the apps from each other. You can change the app/DLL without any chance of breaking one of the other apps. And each time you release a new version of an app you only have to test it with its specific DLL.

Comment: Finally, your proposed scenario is completely different from that in the ToolsAPI. Your proposed approach leads you to tackle binary compatibility across versions, an issue that is simply not present in ToolsAPI. The issues that the interface versioning of ToolsAPI addresses are all about source compatibility.

Comment: I concur fully with David. In our application suite we are deploying a specific server multiple times. Each server instance gets its own folder with its own copies of any dll's it may need. This means duplication when all instances of our server are on the same version, but does allow us to upgrade each instance independently of the others without having to worry about dll versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me explain the logic behind what you've observed with the ToolsAPI and you can then determine how that applies to your situation. Your reasoning is very close.

For interfaces that are meant to be *consumed* by plugins and IDE extensions, you are correct about the manner in which the interfaces are versioned and named. The idea is that existing code will reference a particular interface name and because all the existing methods also exist on that interface. Since the older code simply cannot reference any new methods, it's safe to include them in the new interface.

However if you look closely, for interfaces that are meant to be *implemented* by the plugin or IDE extension, you will see that the reverse is true. The new interfaces get new names and all the older existing interfaces remain unchanged. This is because, as the implementer of the interface you must implement all the methods of an interface. Existing code, by definition, will not have implemented the new methods. When the IDE needs to call a user's implemented method, it will always make that call by querying for the version of the interface on which that method was introduced, which may not be the most recent version of the interface. For this reason one should list all ancestral interfaces as being implemented on the implementing class.

In summary, the rule here for the IDE's ToolsAPI are that for interfaces that plugins use, the newest version of the interface always gets the unversioned name. For interfaces that the plugin implements, new interfaces always get a new name.